# (c++) Is there any techniques using memory rearrange to increase cache hit rate?

Tags: c++, caching, memory

I want to have better performance by increasing cache hit rate.
I know that loop from 0 to n in something like vector is the best way of reducing cache miss, but in my application, the accessing order of the element is changing everytime, I can't use a fixed order. However, it is not totally random, I can assume that for any two continuous round of access (each round will check every element eventually), only a small part is different. I think I can use that features to reduce cache miss but I don't know if there are similar techniques or it is just worthless.

Situation Example:

```
struct Data{
...
}
std::vector<Data> dataList;
void Assignment(std::vector<int> dispatch_order)
{
for(int idx:dispatch_order){ do something with dataList[idx]...}
}
```

Call of `Assignment` will be like: (executing hillclimb or simulated annealing）

```
Assignment({0,1,2,3,4});//move 4 to [1]
Assignment({0,4,1,2,3});//move {2,3} to [0]
Assignment({2,3,0,4,1});//move 0 to last
Assignment({2,3,4,1,0});
```

(so I can say that most of parts are similar for any two continuous `Assignment`).
No modification on `dataList` during entire computation.
Elements of `dataList` is no more than 10000 (2000 in average?), but repetation of `Assignment` is over 1,000,000.

If I can rearrange the data location in `dataList` s.t. `for(int idx:dispatch_order)` will access the element `Data` in almost increasing order in memory space, that would be a better performance. But 'rearrange' costs, is it really a good idea?
Or I can make duplication of `dataList` in different order, but it needs extra memory which might drop down the hit rate and I still need to change the order.

Comment: Measure what you have now so you have a baseline. Make the changes you think might help and measure again and you can tell if it is better or worse.

Comment: Is there any existing conclusion on this kind of problem rather than starting from zero? I think similar problem could appear in game engine or something like solver.

Comment: I've been writing games for a living for over two decades. Profile, modify, profile is just what you do. There's no silver bullet and all programs and platforms are different.